# Reusable JFileChooser for updating image

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am trying to create a function which can preview the image that the user selected from a customized JFileChooser. The following are the code snippets from the test frame and the customized JFileChooser.

Test.java

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private FileChooser file;
    private static JLabel lblPicPreview;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test frame = new Test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Test() {
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("main menu");
        setBounds(100, 100, 960, 540);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));

        lblPicPreview = new JLabel();
        lblPicPreview.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                file.setPic();
            }
        });
        lblPicPreview.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)), "Preview", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        lblPicPreview.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        lblPicPreview.setToolTipText("Click to change profile picture");

        file= new FileChooser();

        contentPane.add(file);
        contentPane.add(lblPicPreview);
    }

    // Method to update image
    public static void updatePicture(ImageIcon icon){
        lblPicPreview.setIcon(icon);
    }

    public void refresh(){
        repaint();
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

FileChooser.java

```
public class FileChooser extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    /**
    *  Constructor FileChooser to place the UI for customized JFileChooser
    */

    // actionPerformed for the "select" button in the custom UI
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        returnVal= fileChooser.showOpenDialog(button);

        if(returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            file= fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            fileLabel.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
            img= new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
            /** caller object to chg icon when user chooses new image
            *   i want to make this to update the image from its caller
            *   something like this
            *   {sourceLabel}.setIcon(img);
            */
            Test.updatePicture(img);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine for the application. The problem is that i wish to make the customized JFileChooser to be reusable for all other frames/ classes. I want to make my custom JFileChooser smart enough to get any caller's class's JLabel (eg. lblPicPreview) to be updated with the chosen image instead of calling Test.java's lblPicPreview.setIcon() from the FileChooser class itself. This is done so that I can use FileChooser for other instances of frames/class.

One problem is that Test.java's lblPicPreview is an instance variable, so i cannot directly use it from FileChooser class.

All helps are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't repost your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876557/reusable-jfilechooser-for-updating-images

Comment: Please [edit this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31876492/edit) to correct the code formatting, and as mentioned by @sʜʀɪɴɪᴠᴀssʜᴜᴋʟᴀ, do not repost questions.

Comment: @sʜʀɪɴɪᴠᴀssʜᴜᴋʟᴀ Sry i double clicked the wrong button twice. I shall delete the duplicate post now. Sry for the trouble.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question so I will just point you to the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Chooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) which contains an example showing how to do an image preview.

Comment: @camickr My custom file chooser is able to prompt user to choose their desired image and display in on the caller Test.java's lblPicPreview, the only thing is I want to make my custom JFileChooser smart enough to get any caller's class's JLabel (eg. lblPicPreview) to be updated with the chosen image instead of calling Test.java's lblPicPreview.setIcon() from the FileChooser class itself. This is done so that I can use FileChooser for other instances of frames/class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a method to specify the label to set:

```
public class FileChooser extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  protectedJLabel activeLabel;

  public void setActivelabel( JLabel label ) {
    activeLabel = label;
  }
}
```